Is there a way to force an Android PWA to go back to its "start_url" from Javascript?
My app dynamically generates manifest.json for each user, so that there can be multiple homescreen shortcuts, each pointing to the user's unique start_url. However, in case of a server error (and other cases), I'd like to have a link that lets the user go back to the initial page for that PWA. And because of the way that the app is designed, I can't use any information provided by the server (session, cookies, generated html, manifest, etc.) -- this has to be done purely in Javascript inside the PWA itself.
It's easy enough to do in iOS, since PWAs are isolated, and have their own sandboxed localstorage. That way, I can save the initial URL into localstorage, and then retrieve it when needed.
But on Android, PWAs share their space with each other and the browser, so I can't find any unique way that I can identify each of the PWAs

How is the users unique manifest fetched from the server - i.e. how does the server know what to send in the start_url?

During normal operation, the server generates the manifest based on the user info (and other things). My problem is generating a "return" or "re-login" link, which happens after the session expires, so the error page has nothing to reference. That's why I need it to be accessible purely from Javascript

It's pretty widely know -- Android doesn't isolate web we apps (at least Chrome definitely doesn't). Not sure about official documentation, but a quick Google search will bring up a plethora of results
